# Multiplying multiple columns in R with a specific large value

Tags: r, raster

I have a dataframe in R

```
> df
             Dataset     a1         b2         c3
1           past        0.0029  0.00250  0.0011
2           present     0.0035  0.00078 -0.0018
3           future1     0.0020  0.02100  0.0200
4           future2    0.0390   0.04000  0.0460
```

How can I multiply the columns of a1,b2 and c3 with value of 4193215.58165948 ?

Comment: df[,2:4] * 4193215.58165948

Comment: Through this I loose my dataset column as well, how can I keep the dataset column intact as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Otto Kässi's approach and use `cbind` to bind it with your Dataset column.

```
df <- cbind(Dataset = df$Dataset, df[,2:4] * 4193215.58165948)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df[,2:4] <- df[,2:4] * 4193215.58165948
```

Or a more explicit (and safe) approach:

```
v <- c("a1", "b2", "c3")
df[,v] <- df[,v] * 4193215.58165948
```